# Remove class on previous slide

Tags: javascript, reactjs, carousel, antd

I'm working on carousel using ant design and reactjs.

Im trying to make this slider [3d smooth carousel](https://codepen.io/gerryl1991/pen/MrRpKZ) and I successfully able to do it.

my problem is on the previous image which is the left side. I cant remove the class that I added every time the carousel change, the class should be always in the last previous slide not on all previous slides.

Hope you understand me.

thanks.

[SAMPLE CODE](https://codesandbox.io/s/9oy1v5w5nw)

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      prev: 0
    };
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }

  onChange(a, b, c) {
    this.setState({
      prev: b
    });
  }
  // onLoad
  componentDidUpdate() {
    var list = document.getElementsByClassName("slick-slide");
    list[this.state.prev].classList.add("prev");
  }
  // onChange
  componentWillUpdate() {
    var list = document.getElementsByClassName("slick-slide");
    list[this.state.prev].classList.add("prev");
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove all ocurrences of the class before asigning it to the new element with this function:

```
function removeClassFromPrevious() {
   var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("prev");

   var array = [].slice.call(elements);

   array.forEach(function(item, index){      
      item.classList.remove("prev");
   });

}
```

So you can call it like this:

```
  // onLoad
  componentDidUpdate() {
    removeClassFromPrevious();
    var list = document.getElementsByClassName("slick-slide");
    list[this.state.prev].classList.add("prev");
  }
  // onChange
  componentWillUpdate() {
    removeClassFromPrevious();
    var list = document.getElementsByClassName("slick-slide");
    list[this.state.prev].classList.add("prev");
  }
```

---

Or in a more reusable way:

```
function removeAllClassOcurrences(className) {
   var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);

   var array = [].slice.call(elements);

   array.forEach(function(item, index){      
      item.classList.remove(className);
   });

}
...
removeAllClassOcurrences("prev");
```

Comment: Hi sir, sorry, when I move the slider to the right the prev class is not showing..

Comment: Can you make a fiddle? The codesandbox doesn't seem to work

Comment: Take a look at your onChange function, only the first parameter `a` is being set. Since you're using the second `b` your state variable is set `undefined` and the code throws an error as is trying to use it as an index.

Comment: https://codepen.io/gerryl1991/pen/yjpLLZ?editors=0110 , late reply sorry

Comment: sir it ok now, you're right about the onChange function, I should use the first parameter instead of b. thanks again sir